# Using set method to allow another class to access array

Tags: java, arrays

I am having trouble with allowing the invoice class access to the array in processinvoice class.

This is what I am specifically need to do.

- Set array of InvoiceItem objects into the Invoice with the set method.

I believe I need to pass the array through setInvoiceItems but everything I have tried hasn't worked. I have tried for the last couple of days and still haven't found out anything.
I am sure it is pretty easy and I am just over thinking it but how would I accomplish this?
My code for both classes are below,

```
public class Invoice {


    private InvoiceItem[] invoiceItems;
    private double totalInvoice;

    public double getTotalInvoice() {
        return totalInvoice;
    }

     void setInvoiceItems(InvoiceItem[] inInvoiceItems) {
        invoiceItems = inInvoiceItems;

    }

    void calculateInvoice() {

        int counter = 0;
        while (counter < invoiceItems.length) {
            totalInvoice += invoiceItems[counter].calculateItemTotal();
            counter++;
        }

        System.out.println("Invoice total" + totalInvoice);

    }

    void displayInvoice() {

        int counter = 0;
        while (counter < invoiceItems.length) {
            invoiceItems[counter].display();
            counter++;
        }

    }
}

public class ProcessInvoice {

    Invoice[] invoices;

    void createInvoiceItems() {

        InvoiceItem[] items = new InvoiceItem[3];

        items[0] = new InvoiceItem();
        items[0].setItemId(123);
        items[0].setItemQuantity(55);
        items[0].setItemPrice(2.99);
        items[0].setItemDescription("Ball");


        items[1] = new InvoiceItem();
        items[1].setItemId(55);
        items[1].setItemQuantity(95);
        items[1].setItemPrice(0.5);
        items[1].setItemDescription("Nails");


        items[2] = new InvoiceItem();
        items[2].setItemId(4235);
        items[2].setItemQuantity(10);
        items[2].setItemPrice(5.68);
        items[2].setItemDescription("Soda");

        invoices.setInvoiceItems(items);
    }


    void runProcess() {

        Invoice[] invoices = new Invoice[1];
        createInvoiceItems();
        invoices[0].calculateInvoice();
        invoices[0].displayInvoice();



    }


}
```

Answer (score 1):

`Invoice[] invoices;` is an array of invoices and the method `setInvoiceItems(..)` is present in `Invoice` object.

You need to create an `Invoice` object. `Invoice invoice = new Invoice();`

Then set the InvoiceItems `invoice.setInvoiceItems(items);`

Comment: you should also address the fact that createInvoiceItems() does not return any value and has no effect outside its own scope.

Comment: I am not totally clear about the design so gave limited answer. If he does keep `Invoice invoice` at instance level as he has kept the `Invoice[] invoices;` array then its OK I think.

Answer (score 1):

You have to return the `InvoiceItem[]` from `createInvoiceItems()` and then set the `InvoiceItem[] into invoices[0] using the same method`. A snippet is shown below. Though, this will set same `InvoiceItem[] in each Invoice of your Invoice[]`

```
InvoiceItem[] createInvoiceItems() {

    InvoiceItem[] items = new InvoiceItem[3];

    items[0] = new InvoiceItem();
    items[0].setItemId(123);
    items[0].setItemQuantity(55);
    items[0].setItemPrice(2.99);
    items[0].setItemDescription("Ball");


    items[1] = new InvoiceItem();
    items[1].setItemId(55);
    items[1].setItemQuantity(95);
    items[1].setItemPrice(0.5);
    items[1].setItemDescription("Nails");


    items[2] = new InvoiceItem();
    items[2].setItemId(4235);
    items[2].setItemQuantity(10);
    items[2].setItemPrice(5.68);
    items[2].setItemDescription("Soda");

    return items;
}

void runProcess() {

    Invoice[] invoices = new Invoice[1];
    //create an Invoice Object
    Invoice invoice = new Invoice();
    invoices[0] = invoice;

    //createInvoiceItems(); // Not required here
    invoices[0].calculateInvoice();
    invoices[0].displayInvoice();
    invoices[0].setInvoiceItems(//call here createInvoiceItems());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

invoices is an array, you're initializing the array but not populating it with any instance of an actual Invoice object:

```
invoices[0] = new Invoice();
```

also, the method `createInvoiceItems()` does not return the InvoiceItem array that it creates, it is just lost once the method finishes its execution.

Answer (score 0):

You have following options

1) make InvoiceItem array in ProcessInvoice  class static, and then you access that array from Invoice class using ProcessInvoice .InvoiceItem. Do this only if your design alllows.

after initializing InvoiceItem array in ProcessInvoice class call  setInvoiceItems method( Be carefull about which instance you are calling with)

```
public class Invoice {
private InvoiceItem[] invoiceItems;
private double totalInvoice;

public double getTotalInvoice() {
    return totalInvoice;
}

 void setInvoiceItems() {
    invoiceItems = ProcessInvoice.Items;

}

void calculateInvoice() {

    int counter = 0;
    while (counter < invoiceItems.length) {
        totalInvoice += invoiceItems[counter].calculateItemTotal();
        counter++;
    }

    System.out.println("Invoice total" + totalInvoice);

}

void displayInvoice() {

    int counter = 0;
    while (counter < invoiceItems.length) {
        invoiceItems[counter].display();
        counter++;
    }

}
}

public class ProcessInvoice {

Invoice[] invoices;
static InvoiceItem[] items;

void createInvoiceItems() {

    InvoiceItem[] items = new InvoiceItem[3];

    items[0] = new InvoiceItem();
    items[0].setItemId(123);
    items[0].setItemQuantity(55);
    items[0].setItemPrice(2.99);
    items[0].setItemDescription("Ball");


    items[1] = new InvoiceItem();
    items[1].setItemId(55);
    items[1].setItemQuantity(95);
    items[1].setItemPrice(0.5);
    items[1].setItemDescription("Nails");


    items[2] = new InvoiceItem();
    items[2].setItemId(4235);
    items[2].setItemQuantity(10);
    items[2].setItemPrice(5.68);
    items[2].setItemDescription("Soda");
    new Invoice().setInvoiceItems();
}
void getInvoiceItems()
{
return items;
}

void runProcess() {

    Invoice[] invoices = new Invoice[1];
    createInvoiceItems();
    invoices[0].calculateInvoice();
    invoices[0].displayInvoice();



}


 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually probem with your code is you are calling the setInvoiceItem method through new object of Invoice, but while you are displaying you are using different object. make sure the array to which you copy the data and the array you are looking for data after copying are of same Instance

Answer (score -2):

You need to implment getter for that array in `ProcessInvoice` class.

```
public class ProcessInvoice {

    private Invoice[] invoices;

    ........

    public Invoice[] getInvoices() {
        return invoices;

    }
}
```

And in your `Invoice` class;

```
public class Invoice {


    private InvoiceItem[] invoiceItems;
    private double totalInvoice;
    private ProcessInvoice processInvoice;

    ......

    void getInvoices() {
        processInvoice = new ProcessInvoice();
        processInvoice.runProcess();
        processInvoice.getInvoices();

    }


}
```

Comment: -1 owner, could you please explain your reason to that downvote?

Comment: OP is creating an invoiceItems array as a local var which is discarded, he's not creating any instance of an Invoice, and in general doesn't understand scope/assignments/initialization. adding a getter solves non of these problems